# SQL Server conditional query for a master detail query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this question. Let's see the query:

```
SELECT
    D.DocumentName,
    D.Title,
    D.Description,
    V.Version,
    CASE 
        WHEN V.State = 'PUB' THEN 'PUBLISHED' 
        WHEN V.State = 'UNP' THEN 'UNPUBLISHED' 
        WHEN V.State IS NULL THEN 'NOT PUBLISHED' 
        ELSE '' 
    END AS State
FROM 
    Document D 
LEFT JOIN 
    DocumentVersion V ON D.IdDocument = V.IdDocumentVersion
```

This is a typical master-detail table (Document-DocumentVersion). A `Document` can have one or more `DocumentVersions` or none. A `DocumentVersion` state can be `PUBLISHED` or `UNPUBLISHED`. The `PUBLISHED` one `DocumentVersion` can exist just once for a `Document` (this is controlled by application), but there can exist many `UNPUBLISHED`, or all `DocumentVersions` are `UNPUBLISHED`. NOT `PUBLISHED` doesn't exist, it's just a word in the query result when there's no `DocumentVersion` record for a `Document`, that's the reason for the `LEFT JOIN`.

So my question is: how can I make the query accomplish the next rules?

- If a `DocumentVersion` state is `PUB`, ignore the others, I mean don't show the `UNP` ones in the query result for this `Document`
- If a `DocumentVersion` state is `UNP` (and here can be many `UNP`), then show only the one with the highest date of `Unpublish` (`DocumentVersion` table has a `UnPublishDate` column), this rule applies just when there's no `PUB` `DocumentVersion` for the document

I would appreciate any help you can give me, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  You can do it using `row_number()` or `rank()`:

```
select d.*, dv.*
from d left join
     (select dv.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dv.IdDocument
                                order by (case when dv.state = 'PUB' then 1
                                               when dv.state = 'UNP' then 2
                                               else 3
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from documentversion dv
     ) dv
     on dv.IdDocument = d.IdDocument and
        seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  I don't think the join condition is correct in your question.

Comment: with your approach the 'UNP' ones shows the state with the lowest UnPublishedDate and I need the highest one, additionally I need the cases when there´s not DocumentVersion for a Document, for this reason I use the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Oh, I think Gordon just missed off ', UnPublishDate desc' from the end of his order by and needed to do a left outer join instead.  My query's pretty much the same

Comment: now yours works fine whith your edit and adding "UnPublishDate desc" as @VorpulusLyphane suggested. There's a conceptual thing that I'm trying to understand. Why with the "partition by dv.IdDocument" works as I desire but "partition by dv.IdDocumentVersion" don't? Why this affect?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from Document D
left outer join
  (select *, 
  row_number()over(partition by IdDocumentVersion order by state asc, UnPublishDate desc) as row
  from DocumentVersion) V
on D.IdDocument = V.IdDocumentVersion
and V.row = 1
```

State asc is a bit of a hack by the way that just happens to work in this case.  You might want to be more explicit with a 'case when' (see Gordon's answer).

Comment: Thank you. added the "UnPublishDate desc" with the Edit (@Gordon) he makes and works, but I don't understand a thing, please see my last coment to @Gordon.

Comment: Gordon somehow managed to correctly predict the presence of an IdDocument column in your DV table (this column appeared nowhere in your 'working' query) with such confidence that he actually used it in his answer. I assumed - wrongly, it turns out - that you simply poorly named the column representing the document id as IDDocumentVersion. In other words, both queries aimed to partition by the same thing: DocumentID. You partition by DocumentID so that, for every DocumentID, you can rank the Versions in order of preference (PUB over UNP, then later version over earlier) and take the top one.

Comment: Thank's for your help.